# Question closed and locked but can't down vote to get off front page after a year?

Tags: support, status-completed, locked-question

Why is the question [Pros and cons of PHP vs C,C++ as language in a programming interview? [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/pros-and-cons-of-php-vs-c-c-as-language-in-a-programming-interview) locked?

I mean it is one thing to close it, I agree with that, it meets at least 3 criteria for closing.

Locking it means it can't be down voted off the front page!

It also can't commented on or edited to correct mistakes or make it a better question for re-opening, even though I doubt that would happen.

If it is going to stay locked, it should just be deleted as it is just noise on the front page, and has been for a long time seeing as the actual question and last edit is a over a year old!

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jixbb.png]

It appears that this question only exists on programmers and not stackoverflow, at least I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this behavior might have to do with the migration being rejected. But the behavior is not that intuitive, and it might be something different. My understanding is that if a question is migrated and then closed on the receiving site, the migration is rejected. The question simply ends up closed on both sites.

Comment: `closed` on both sizes is ok, but `locked` isn't, I think `locked` should be used for a completely different purpose, this should be unlocked/editable or deleted.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I agree. Perhaps this is more of an issue for MSO, since if I'm right and it is a product of a rejected migration, it's a network issue and not a Programmers issue. But I'm not confident enough to say that is what is happening here - this is just my best guess.

Answer (score 2):

The question was migrated over a year ago - March 2011 - so the stub has long been deleted, April 2011 in fact.

I'd unlock the question if it were newer and potentially more constructive, but I don't think any amount of editing can salvage it now.

I was waiting for somebody to spring to the question's defence, but as that wasn't forthcoming I've just deleted it.

Comment: so it will just rot taking up space on the front page forever?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - it can be deleted. I was going to do that when I first saw this question but I thought I'd hold off until we'd had chance to discuss it.

Comment: wheres the discussion? you mean between the moderators, or the community in general?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - I was hoping that there would have been some discussion on the merits (or otherwise) of the question on this thread. As there hasn't been I'll just go ahead and delete it.

Comment: well I for one wasted some time reviewing question and its answers. None looks worth discussing. The top-voted answer could better be rephrased to something like "take a look at questions in [tag:pseudocode] tag" - which makes it harmless, but not terribly valuable. Overall impression - question and answers are rather a waste of screen space, deleting it won't do harm

Comment: I agree with @gnat, deleting it would do no harm to anyone other than the semi-non-answer that has 21 upvotes. I think if it could be unlocked and downvoted off the front page that would be just as well. But I don't think that can happen, so I would just delete it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - deleted.

Comment: @YannisRizos Only moderators can (vote to) delete locked posts.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Damn, those rejected migrations are quite messy...